# Select a random item from User's Music Library (iOS) (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, mpmediaquery, mpmedialibrary

How to select a random song/album/playlist from the user's library?

Also, how to select all the songs from a particular artist/genre at random?

I have tried `MPMediaQuery`, but am somehow not able to achieve what I want. All I get is all the available songs for a specific group (artist, album, genre, etc.,)

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried MPMediaQuery, but am somehow not able to achieve what I want. All I get is all the available songs for a specific group

If you form a complete empty MPMediaQuery you get a list of all songs. Now you can pick one at random.